# django file field isn't showing up the first time when I load the page

Tags: python, django

I have a django html page that should show a upload button and a place where you can place your files.
the first time when I load the page only the upload button is there. After I click on the button the choose your file button appears.

Is there a possebility that the choose file always shows?

[image: loading webpage first time]

[image: after I clicked on upload]

**HTML code**

```
        <form action="{% url "result" %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/result/" class="form-horizontal">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name" class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 control-label">File: </label>
                <p>{{ form }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload" style="margin-right:5px;"></span>Upload </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def result(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
                data = request.FILES['file']
                handle_uploaded_file(data)
                data = pd.read_csv(data,header=0, sep=',')
                result = getPredictions(data)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request, 'result.html', {'result': result})
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: I would say it's a CSS issue.

Comment: great suggestion but that doesn't seem to be the case. I've removed the css from the html files and it still doesn't work